# Can a button element have childNodes?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, nodes

If I have a `<b>` inside `<button>` tags, is the `<b>` therefore a childNode of the `<button>` tags? consider the code below:

```
<button id='mooo'><b>Cows can't mooo</b></button>
```

Javascript:

```
x = document.getElementById('mooo');
x.addEventListener("Click", mooo);

function mooo(e){
if(e.target.childNode == "B"){
console.log("B is a child of Button");
}else{
console.log("B is not a child of Button");
}
```

The code returns the latter, but I just need to be sure if B is indeed not a child of BUTTON

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `button` elements are elements with content. You're just not checking their content correctly; there is no `childNode` property on elements. There are `childNodes` (a collection), `firstChild`, `lastChild`, and their element versions `children`, `firstElementChild`, and `lastElementChild`, but no `childNode`.

You've also used `Click` rather than `click` (event names are case-sensitive), and `e.target` which could be the `b` element rather than the `button` (you'd want `this` or `e.currentTarget` to know you were referencing the `button`).

Live example:

```js
var x = document.getElementById('mooo');
x.addEventListener("click", mooo);

function mooo() {
  if (this.firstElementChild.tagName == "B") {
    console.log("B is a child of Button");
  } else {
    console.log("B is not a child of Button");
  }
  console.log("Contents of the button:");
  for (let child = this.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) {
    switch (child.nodeType) {
      case 1: // Element
        console.log(child.tagName + " element, innerHTML = " + child.innerHTML);
        break;
      case 3: // Text node
        console.log("Text node, nodeValue = " + child.nodeValue);
        break;
      default:
        console.log(child.nodeName);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button id='mooo'><b>Cows can't mooo</b></button>
```

In contrast, `input type="button"` elements are [*void elements*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#void-elements); they can't have content, their `childNodes` collection is always empty.

Comment: Thanks :) I made a mistake when I rewrote the code here... the click event is fine on my actual code. Also, why switch case, instead of regular for loop?

Comment: @JamesBaloyi He is using a regular loop. The `switch` is inside the loop and is another form for writing `if/then` logic.